# SwiftUI .hoverEffect on view with Material background blacks out view

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios-simulator, ipados

I have a view with a material background fill. When applying a hoverEffect to this view, the view becomes blacked out on hover.

[image: Demonstration]

Very minimal reproducible code:

```swift
ZStack {
    Rectangle()
        .fill(Material.thinMaterial)
    
    Text("lift")
}
.hoverEffect(.lift)


ZStack {
    Rectangle()
        .fill(Material.thinMaterial)
    
    Text("highlight")
}
.hoverEffect(.highlight)
```

I'm not sure if this is intended behaviour, as `.lift` is stated to produce ["An effect that ... as the view scales up and *gains a shadow.*"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/hovereffect/lift) However, the same things happens with `.highlight`, where it is not supposed to produce any shadows under the view when hovered.

Note: This happens on real hardware and within simulators. I have tested in iPadOS 16.1 and 15.5 simulators, and I can replicate this behaviour in both.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be fixed in versions >16.3!